# Perform a jQuery event before opening up a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple javascript/jQuery related question:

I have the following markup in my tumblr blog:

```
<a href="/page/#" class="pagination">NEXT</a>
```

The # above changes according to which page the user is on. ie: # is variable, and cannot be static.

With jQuery, I would like to perform an effect (`slideUp();`, to be specific) **before** the new link is opened.

Is that possible?

I have tried both `.click()` and `.mousedown()`. Doesn't seem to work, since when I click the link, the new page opens up before any effects take place.

I have heard of `preventDefault()`, but I'd like to shy away from that, for that would mean I must create a separate function to detect the page #, etc. (too much work~)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend against doing that. Just let the user change pages.

However, if you really want to, what you need to do is indeed `preventDefault` (explicitly, or by returning `false` from your handler), do the `slideUp`, and then in the `slideUp` completion function, trigger the change in URL.

Like this:

```
$("a.pagination").click(function() {
    // Grab the link's href
    var href = this.href;

    // Slide up the content you want to slide up
    $("some_selector_here").slideUp(function() {
        // Slide is finished, navigate
        location.href = href;
    });

    // Prevent the default action of the link
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to defer changing of page's url:

```
$('.pagination').click(function(){
    var link = this;
    $('.some-other-element').slideUp(500, function(){
        location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
    });
    return false;
});
```